# Drawing borders only for common border of polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, expression, geometry-generator, borders

I would like to style a polygon layer in a way that only those borders that **do** touch other polygons are drawn.

In this very basic example, it would look (roughly) like this. Just that in this case I drew the lines;)

[image]

The idea is that I want to draw the borders between countries, but not the coastlines. The example QGIS Project can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1AEKu4TKpzJg95oXv8dxep24xpXaesr0F?usp=sharing).

Comment: I may be missing something but it looks to me that in your visual example you only drew borders that are shared with more than one polygon in contrast to your text request to draw only those borders that do not touch other polygons.

Comment: Agree with @John. Your visual example seems to show the exact opposite of your written request.

Comment: totally true!! I took the **not** out of the questions! I actually would like to draw country borders, but not the coastlines. That was the intention

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Geometry Generator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) with this expression (alternatively, you could also use [`intersection()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=overlay_contains#intersection) instead of [`shared_paths()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=overlay_contains#shared-paths) function):

```
collect_geometries(
    array_foreach(
        overlay_intersects (@layer, boundary($geometry)),
        shared_paths (@element, boundary($geometry))
    )
)
```

*I applied the Geometry Generator to a duplicated layer of your polygon layer:*
[image]

Comment: thank you so much! I was kinda close but would not have got it:)

Comment: sorry, I just do have one (potentially silly) question. Why do you need the call to `boundary($geometry)` as an expression? And what does it exactly do in this context? Couldn't I just use `$geometry`?

Comment: `$geometry` here is a polygon. We want lines instead. That's why I used `boundary($geometry)` to convert the polygons to lines, the outer boundaries.